Simple Kafka Producer/Consumer - Consumer not consuming all messages
I'm just playing around with Kafka in order to evaluate it for future projects.  Below are two python scripts using some sample code based on the kafka-python library.   I am trying to figure out why when I publish 100 messages from the producer I get < 100 messages on the consumer.

Standard out of the box Kafka broker setup
Consumer (and only one Consumer) started using below code to consumer all messages from the 'quickstart-events' topic
Producer will list on screen messages msg0,msg1....msg99 published
Consumer however will only report maybe msg0,msg1...msg70 consumed and not the full 100

One thing to note, if I put in a small time.sleep(2/1000) delay in the publisher THEN the consumer will report all 100 messages being consumed.  This to me suggests that maybe broker is not capable of handling all the messages that the producer publishes?  To me this seems to be implausible.  Note that when I created the topic I created it with just one partition.
Sample producer output:
For every message that the Producer publishes to the topic then every message must be received by the Consumer process running and subscribing to that same topic.
    # producer.py
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
    from kafka.errors import KafkaError
    import time

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['msg1:9092'])

    # Asynchronous by default
    future = producer.send('quickstart-events', b'raw_bytes')

    for i in range(1,100):
        key = f"key{i}"
        msg = f"msg{i}"
        print(f"Publish message {msg}")
        future = producer.send(topic='quickstart-events', key=key.encode(), value=msg.encode())
        #putting in the 2ms sleep DOES allow for all messages to be received    
        #time.sleep(2/1000)

    # consumer.py
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer

    # To consume latest messages and auto-commit offsets
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('quickstart-events',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['msg1:9092'])

    for message in consumer:
        # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
        # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
        print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                          message.offset, message.key,
                                          message.value))


As you can see in this example messages: msg93,msg94...msg99 are missing
# Publisher output
Publish message msg1
Publish message msg2
Publish message msg3
....
Publish message msg97
Publish message msg98
Publish message msg99

  # Consumer output
quickstart-events:0:3850: key=None value=b'raw_bytes'
quickstart-events:0:3851: key=b'key1' value=b'msg1'
quickstart-events:0:3852: key=b'key2' value=b'msg2'
quickstart-events:0:3853: key=b'key3' value=b'msg3'
.....
quickstart-events:0:3940: key=b'key90' value=b'msg90'
quickstart-events:0:3941: key=b'key91' value=b'msg91'
quickstart-events:0:3942: key=b'key92' value=b'msg92'


I'm not a python expert, but it looks like the future is not waited, so maybe the message was never delivered --> future = producer.send(topic='quickstart-events', key=key.encode(), value=msg.encode())

You need to call producer.flush() after the loop, otherwise the script will exit with pending records in the producer buffer
You should also be able to add a delivery report function to the producer send function rather than logging before the record is actually sent and acknowledged by the broker
